# Split .csv to arrays

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

I have a CSV file containing 2 rows of information. I want to work with both at the same time but not as 1 array.

In this example my CSV looks like this :

```
Name ;Computer

user1 ;Comp1
user2 ;Comp2
user3 ;Comp3
user4 ;Comp4
```

My goal is to use Computer and Name to add owner to computer in AD based on values in my CSV. For this to work I feel like I need split these values in to 2 arrays witch i can then just for each loop

Comment: do you mean AD-Computer ownership? or you fill some other value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution for my problem, as my list was complete and in order i split the csv to 2 files and used this code to finish the job

```
$names = Get-Content Names.txt
$comp = Get-Content computers.txt

for($x=0; $x -lt $comp.length; $x++)
{
    Write-Host $comp[$x]
    Write-Host $names[$x]
    Get-ADComputer $comp[$x] -Properties * | Set-ADComputer -ManagedBy $names[$x]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a separate array for each column of your CSV like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv'

$names     = $csv | Select-Object -Expand Name
$computers = $csv | Select-Object -Expand Computer
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `CSV` file does not seem to be well-formatted because of additional spaces. Here's by beginner's solution:

Read `Get-Help 'about_Split' -ShowWindow`

```
$separator = " ;"            ### or $separator = " ", ";"
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$myFile = 'D:\bat\SO\34718014.csv'

ForEach ($strLine in Get-Content $myFile) {
    $asplit = $strLine.Split($separator, $option)
    if (($asplit[0] + $asplit[1] -ne "NameComputer") -and ($asplit[0] + $asplit[1] -ne $Null)) {
        '['+$asplit[0]+']['+$asplit[1]+']' #debug output
        #
        # place your code to add owner to computer in AD here
        #
    } else {
        "skipped line: " + $strLine # debug output: skipped CSV header, skipped empty line(s)
    }
}
```

For modified Ansgar Wiechers' solution (no doubt smarter than my beginner's one), read `Get-Help 'Import-Csv' -ShowWindow`. However, it keeps additional trailing spaces in `$Names`:

```
Write-Host "Ansgar Wiechers' solution:"

$csv = Import-Csv 'D:\bat\SO\34718014.csv' -Delimiter ";"

$names     = $csv | Select-Object -Expand "Name "
$computers = $csv | Select-Object -Expand Computer

For ($i=0; $i -le $names.Count; $i++) {
    ('[' + $names[$i] + '][' + $computers[$i] + ']')
}
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\34718014.ps1
skipped line: Name ;Computer
skipped line: 
[user1][Comp1]
[user2][Comp2]
[user3][Comp3]
[user4][Comp4]
Ansgar Wiechers' solution:
[user1 ][Comp1]
[user2 ][Comp2]
[user3 ][Comp3]
[user4 ][Comp4]
[][]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `split()` function.
Some good info is here: http://ss64.com/ps/split.html
but basically:

```
$demo = "abc ;def"
$items = $demo.split(' ;')
```